# View Center property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two views. one is parent and other is subview. Suppose the parent view width and height is 480 X 320 and child view width and height is 1600 X 320. NOw I want to scroll the child view and make sure that it stops when the content size is over. I know it can be achieve via UIScrollView but I want to do it without using UISCrollView.

Comment: First tell me which is sequence of  hight and width you assume  (h * w) or (w * h) ??

Comment: You mention the center property.  What's wrong with adjusting that in the subview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand this correctly: You have a "screenView" (the smaller view that clips to bounds) and a "contentView" (the large one that is a subview of the "screenView") and you would like to move the center of contentView but you are unable to calculate where the borders of a center are so that the contentView always fully overlaps the screenView.

```
CGFloat xMin = screenView.frame.size.width - contentView.frame.size.width*.5f;
CGFloat yMin = screenView.frame.size.height - contentView.frame.size.height*.5f;

CGFloat xMax = contentView.frame.size.width*.5f;
CGFloat yMax = contentView.frame.size.height*.5f;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is above calculated point will be included in the centre of the content view?